# Why is my iframe not scrolling properly after importance is applied to overflow-y CSS

Tags: css, iframe, scroll, overflow, vertical-scrolling

After adding overflow-y: scroll !important to the iframe's css, I am still unable to achieve the y-axis scrollbar feature. It's a major problem due to a form within the iframe which cannot be completed due to its contents being cut off.

HTML

```
<div style="display: none;" id="io-iframe"><iframe scrolling="yes" src="..." frameborder="no" height="2000px"></iframe></div>
```

CSS

```
   iframe {
        display: block;
        height: 2000px;  
        width: 100vw; 
        border: none;
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        overflow: auto !important;
    }

@media all and (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    iframe {
        height: 500vh;  
    }
}
```

When inspecting the page, I see there's `scrolling="no"` and `style="overflow: hidden"` and I have no clue how it's getting appended and if it's the reason why the scrolling functionality isn't working.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeoWQ.jpg)

Comment: You really need to provide a proper [mre] of the issue when asking questions like this, not just a few snippets that lack context.

Comment: Seeing how your iframe element also got the ID `iFrameResizer0` in that screenshot, I'm guessing it is probably some sort of "iframe resizer" script at play, that tries to resize iframes to their actual content's height, so that scrolling won't be _necessary_ any more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least part of the problem is that you're applying some relatively large heights to the iframe itself. When the iframe itself is quite large you could run into the issue that you're scrolling the parent page rather than the iframe itself particularly if its scrollbars are obscured.

Some recommendations:

1. Avoid setting large fixed heights on the iframe, particularly if you do not control its contents.
2. Ennsure you avoid the `scrolling="no"` attribute on the iframe. The default value is `"yes"` so omitting the attribute is all that's needed.

```css
iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 
    These values are 90vh / vw here so it'll
    work in the stackoverflow code snippet runner,
    when you control the page, you can make these 100
  */
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://jvdl.dev/stackoverflow/78104983.html" />
```